# How to calculate average of 2nd field from files?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, awk, date

I have a file and it consists of two fields.
The first field format is **"%FT%T"**.

Sample data:

```
2019-01-01T00:00:00  4.8
2019-01-01T01:00:00  5.1
2019-01-01T02:00:00  5.4
2019-01-01T03:00:00  5.7
2019-01-01T04:00:00  5.8
2019-01-01T05:00:00  5.4
2019-01-01T06:00:00  5
2019-01-01T07:00:00  4.4
2019-01-01T08:00:00  3.8
2019-01-01T09:00:00  3.7
2019-01-01T10:00:00  3.8
2019-01-01T11:00:00  4.1
2019-01-01T12:00:00  5
2019-01-01T13:00:00  6.7
2019-01-01T14:00:00  8.4
2019-01-01T15:00:00  9.1
2019-01-01T16:00:00  8.6
2019-01-01T17:00:00  8.5
2019-01-01T18:00:00  8.6
2019-01-01T19:00:00  8.1
2019-01-01T20:00:00  8
2019-01-01T21:00:00  6.9
2019-01-01T22:00:00  5.6
2019-01-01T23:00:00  5.2
2019-01-02T00:00:00  5.2
2019-01-02T01:00:00  5.3
2019-01-02T02:00:00  5.8
2019-01-02T03:00:00  6
2019-01-02T04:00:00  5.7
2019-01-02T05:00:00  5.4
2019-01-02T06:00:00  5.7
2019-01-02T07:00:00  5.3
2019-01-02T08:00:00  4.8
2019-01-02T09:00:00  4.3
2019-01-02T10:00:00  3.6
2019-01-02T11:00:00  2.8
2019-01-02T12:00:00  3.2
2019-01-02T13:00:00  4.2
2019-01-02T14:00:00  4.9
2019-01-02T15:00:00  5.4
2019-01-02T16:00:00  5.9
2019-01-02T17:00:00  6.5
2019-01-02T18:00:00  6.7
2019-01-02T19:00:00  7.1
2019-01-02T20:00:00  5.7
2019-01-02T21:00:00  4.4
2019-01-02T22:00:00  4.1
2019-01-02T23:00:00  3.8
2019-01-03T00:00:00  4
2019-01-03T01:00:00  3.5
2019-01-03T02:00:00  3.6
2019-01-03T03:00:00  4
2019-01-03T04:00:00  4.2
2019-01-03T05:00:00  3.9
2019-01-03T06:00:00  3.7
2019-01-03T07:00:00  3.8
2019-01-03T08:00:00  3.7
2019-01-03T09:00:00  3.7
2019-01-03T10:00:00  4
2019-01-03T11:00:00  4.7
2019-01-03T12:00:00  5.4
2019-01-03T13:00:00  6.5
2019-01-03T14:00:00  7.6
2019-01-03T15:00:00  7.7
2019-01-03T16:00:00  7.3
2019-01-03T17:00:00  7.4
2019-01-03T18:00:00  8
2019-01-03T19:00:00  8.5
2019-01-03T20:00:00  8.1
2019-01-03T21:00:00  6.5
2019-01-03T22:00:00  5.6
2019-01-03T23:00:00  5.6
```

I want to calculate daily average of 2nd column.

Output should be as follows...

```
01-01-2019 6.1
02-01-2019 5.1
03-01-2019 5.5
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us: i) some real file names, ii) a few lines from each of those files and iii) the output you would expect from that example.

Comment: @terdon I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An awk approach:

```
$ awk '{ 
    date=substr($1,1,10); 
    tot[date]+=$2; 
    num[date]++
    }
    END{
        for(date in tot){
            printf "%s %.1f\n", date,tot[date]/num[date]
        }
    }' file 
2019-01-01 6.1
2019-01-02 5.1
2019-01-03 5.5
```

Comment: It works this sample file butI tried it for different lines. Ouput was incorrect if I didn't miss sth.

Comment: @chess_freak I can't help you if you don't tell me what happened! It works with the file you showed, if you are now using it on something else, then you would have to show us what you are using it on, what output you were expecting and what you are actually getting. In other words, please ask a new question if you now need something different. Or, if it isn't different, make sure your example matches your real data.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I double-check. The only problem is that output is random but values are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
$ mlr --nidx --repifs put '
    $1 = strftime(strptime($1,"%FT%T"),"%d-%m-%Y")
  ' then stats1 -a mean -f 2 -g 1 file
01-01-2019 6.070833
02-01-2019 5.075000
03-01-2019 5.458333
```

Formatting the results seems to be an area in which Miller is somewhat lacking, so if you need that I suggest piping the results through `numfmt` ex.

```
$ mlr --nidx --repifs put '
    $1 = strftime(strptime($1,"%FT%T"),"%d-%m-%Y")
  ' then stats1 -a mean -f 2 -g 1 file | numfmt --field=2 --format='%.1f'
01-01-2019      6.1
02-01-2019      5.1
03-01-2019      5.5
```

---

Alternatively, with a sufficiently recent version of GNU awk and using `mktime` to index the `sum` and `count` arrays with the epoch time of the date:

```
gawk '
  {
    split($1,dt,"[-T:]");
    k = mktime(sprintf("%04d %02d %02d 00 00 00", dt[1], dt[2], dt[3]));
    sum[k] += $2; count[k] += 1;
  }
  END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
    for(k in count) printf "%s %.1f\n", strftime("%d-%m-%Y",k), sum[k]/count[k];
  }
' file
```

---

Another alternative using `csvsql`/`csvformat` from the Python-based `csvkit`:

```
$ csvsql -d ' ' -HS --query '
    SELECT strftime("%d-%m-%Y",date(a)) AS [Day], round(avg(b),1) AS [Avg] FROM file GROUP BY date(a)
  ' file | csvformat -T
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/agate/table/from_csv.py:88: RuntimeWarning: Column names not specified. "('a', 'b')" will be used as names.
Day Avg
01-01-2019  6.1
02-01-2019  5.1
03-01-2019  5.5
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I investigate deeply it. I also find it `https://github.com/johnkerl/miller`

Comment: Should I install python3 ? I don't understand your the latest solution.

Comment: @chess_freak to use the `csvsql` solution, you will need to install the `csvkit` package